# How can display data in table as like as my below screenshot?

Tags: php, mysql

I have list of data in mysql. like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. I need to display in table those data as like as my screenshot. Also include input field and value will associated with vertical and horizontal value. Like: 1_2, 2_3. If my question is not clear please ask me. Please see my attached screenshot.

[image]

here is my code:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
<?php
$row=10;
$cell=10;
for ($x = 1; $x < $row; $x++) {
echo "<tr>";
for ($c = 1; $c < $cell; $c++) {
    if($x>$c){
        echo '<td></td>';
    }else{
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="" value="'.$x.'_'.$c.'" /></td>';    
    }
 }

 echo "</tr>";
} 
?>
</table>
```

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you, what have you tried to get the desired result?

Comment: How? you write code. once you have some code (and not just `<?php // stuff goes here ?>` boilerplate, we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: Please see my code above that I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
 <table width="100%" border="1">
<?php
$row=9;
$cell=9;

for ($x = 1; $x < $row; $x++) {
    if($x == 1) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($c = 1; $c < $cell; $c++) {
            echo '<td>'.($c+1).'</td>';
         }
        echo "</tr>";   
    }
echo "<tr>";
for ($c = 1; $c < $cell; $c++) {

    if($x>$c){
        echo '<td></td>';
    }else{
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="" value="'.$x.'_'.($c+1).'" /></td>';    
    }
 }

 echo "</tr>";
} 
?>
</table>
```

Comment: how can I add left and top title like as my screenshot? left would be start 1 to 8 and top will be start from 2 to 9....

Comment: Updated my cod for top row.

Comment: working on left columns.

Comment: thanks it's working now fine here.

Comment: @Md.RaisulIslamSohag You are Welcome